# How to open a mat file in C?

Tags: c, matlab, import

I am trying to get a variable from a mat file in C. My matfile contains only one matrix called "X(1,1:1024)".
I found the following code to open a mat file in C:

```
#include "mat.h"
MatFile *matGetVariable(MATFile *mfp, const char *name);
```

Can I use the command like this:

```
#include "mat.h"

int main(void)
{
double MatFile[1024];
MatFile *matGetVariable(MATFile *mfp, const char *name);
return(0);
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You cannot do this if you don't have MATLAB. It's not only `mat.h`, but you'd also need libraries shipped with MATLAB for your program to link and run. You can look into the Octave project, it has a MAT-file reading module. There's also a Python module that can read MAT-files. Both are open-source projects where you can take code from.

Comment: I have installed Matlab. In which section can I find the header file mat.h. I was only able to find a file called "math.h"

Comment: All of this is described in the documentation. See here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/mat-file-library-and-include-files.html . Also look here, where it says that you should use the `mex` command to build your program: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/applications-to-read-and-write-matlab-mat-files.html

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thank you for the link! In my case, I probably just need to use matGetVariable. I am not quite sure about the syntax in C. Is it enough to save the data from the variable X (from the mat file called ma) to the array MATFile in C like this: MATFile *matGetVariable(ma *mfp, X *name);

Comment: If you only need to import/export data from .mat files and if you do not want dependencies from MATLAB,  matio open source library can be an alternative.
https://github.com/tbeu/matio
https://github.com/ami-iit/matio-cpp (c++ wrapper)